# Public uploaded files not showing

Tags: linux, filesystems, laravel-5.7

I'm having problems with displaing uploaded files on public folder. I always get 404 error every time I try to load files from public folder.

All tests over file uplad pass well, file can be loaded, file is present in database and in public folder, the symlink is created but I can't display contents from public folder.

the main parts of the code:

uploaderController.php

```
$path = $request->file( 'userfile' )->store( 'logos', 'public' );
```

after this the folder in:

```
/storage/app/public/logos/file.ext
```

using the file in blade template:

```
<img src="{{ asset( $model->image_path ) }}" />
```

response from the browser **404 - Page not found**

more info about the server folders:

```
/public/storage  - this is the symlink to the public folder 777 permission
/storage/app/public  - the storage public folder 775 permission
/storage/app/public/logos  - the logo folder 755 permission
/storage/app/public/logos/file.ext  - the file 644 permission
```

I try change permission to 775 on file but always 404

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks

[edit]
I found a difference from another server where I can see public files. The symlink in that server has a green background when ls -l

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question is that inside uploaderController.php when you save the path of your uploaded file you MUST prepend the "storage" folder.

uploaderController.php

```
$path = $request->file( 'userfile' )->store( 'logos', 'public' );

$data = [ 'image_path'=>"storage/{$path}" ];
$model->update( $data );
```